# How do I solve "Undefined color `\dtlpie@segcolix '"?

Tags: color, datatool

I have the following LaTeX file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex,active,tightpage]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{2mm}
\usepackage{datapie}
%\usepackage{xcolor} 
%\xdefinecolor{\dtlpie@segcolix }{rgb}{.8,.6,.4} <- didn't work

\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
    \DTLloaddb{myDB}{local-disk-space-piechart-2013-07-08.csv}
    \DTLdisplaydb{myDB}
    \DTLpiechart{variable=\Space,outerlabel=\Part}{myDB}{\Part=Part,\Space=Space}
    %\DTLdisplaydb{myDB} <- this works
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

with this csv file:

```
Part,Space
programs,18124.8
movies,21606.4
source code,6246.4
VMs,3788.8
Android SDK,1228.8
Audio files,917.0
.cache,832.1
.config,358.5
Desktop,341.3
misc,829.44
```

which I compile like this within a Makefile:

```
pdflatex source.tex -output-format=pdf
```

I have no idea how I can get rid of the error:

```
[...]
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))

! Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `\dtlpie@segcolix '.

See the xcolor package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.12 ...abel=\Part}{myDB}{\Part=Part,\Space=Space}

? 
! Emergency stop.
 ...                                              

l.12 ...abel=\Part}{myDB}{\Part=Part,\Space=Space}

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on local-disk-space-piechart.log.
make: *** [make] Error 1
```

Do you know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [`datapie`](http://ctan.org/pkg/datatool) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/datatool/datatool-user.pdf) (section **7.3 Pie Chart Colours**, p 131):

> The `datapie` package predefines colours for the first eight segments
>   of the pie chart. If you require more than eight segments or if you
>   want to change the default colours, you will need to use
>
> ```
> \DTLsetpiesegmentcolor{<n>}{<color>}
> ```
>
> The first argument `<n>` is the segment index (starting from 1), and
>   the second argument `<color>` is a colour specifier as used in
>   commands such as `\color`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

% Data
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
Part,Space
programs,18124.8
movies,21606.4
source code,6246.4
VMs,3788.8
Android SDK,1228.8
Audio files,917.0
.cache,832.1
.config,358.5
Desktop,341.3
misc,829.44
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{2mm}
\usepackage{datapie}

\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
  \DTLsetpiesegmentcolor{9}{green!40!yellow}% Additional colour for segment 9
  \DTLsetpiesegmentcolor{10}{green!40!pink!20!black}% Additional colour for segment 10
  \DTLloaddb{myDB}{data.csv}
  \DTLdisplaydb{myDB}
  \DTLpiechart{variable=\Space,outerlabel=\Part}{myDB}{\Part=Part,\Space=Space}
  %\DTLdisplaydb{myDB} <- this works
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

By default, eight colours are assigned by pie chart. But you are using ten data and require ten colours. The nineth and tenth colours should be defined to get rid of the error.

```
\DTLsetpiesegmentcolor{9}{cyan}
\DTLsetpiesegmentcolor{10}{brown}
```

Please try this command before `\begin{document}`. Also, see page 77 of `datatool.pdf` (`texdoc datapie`) for additional instructions.